# Is it possible to specify a cache policy?

Tags: swift, siesta-swift

Is it possible in [Siesta](https://github.com/bustoutsolutions/siesta) to use a cache policy like:

- LocalOnly
- NetworkFirst

Where *LocalOnly* is getting the data from the local cache only, and *NetworkFirst* is getting the data from the network, and if it fails, retrieve from local cache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@nikano’s answer is correct if you want to control the cache behavior of `URLSession` when using it as Siesta’s underlying networking library.

In general, Siesta lets the underlying networking do its thing. Options valid for `URLSession` remain the same even when you use it with Siesta.

---

Siesta *itself* is an observable in-memory cache. One of its core design features is that it gives you fine-grained control over which data you see, cached or fresh — and that crucially is not an either/or question. You can use both.

If you want to see the data cached locally in memory, your “local only,” just ask a resource for it:

```
resource.latestData
```

If you want to *force* a network request even if there is cached data, i.e. your “network only:”

```
resource.load().onSuccess { ...use the data... }
```

…and if for some reason you want to request up-to-date data but *not* have Siesta cache it:

```
resource.request(.get).onSuccess { ... }
```

However, the most common idiom is to use *both* the cached and fresh data:

```
resource.addObserver(somethingObserverThatUsesTheData)
resource.loadIfNeeded()
```

In that case, `somethingObserverThatUsesTheData` first sees the locally cached data (if any), then sees the data that comes back from the network library (if there was a network request).

---

Note that the data that comes back from the network library might itself be cached. In most situations, I recommend disabling `URLSession`’s cache so that you know you are getting up-to-date data. However, having two layers of caching might be the right thing in some circumstances.

Comment: Thanks for such a detailed explanation @PaulCantrell. And if I need to support offline mode, should I build a cache that implements https://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Protocols/EntityCache.html ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do so by using `URLSessionConfiguration`

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
    configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders

// cache policy
configuration.requestCachePolicy = .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData
```

The cache policy is an enum defined in `NSURLRequest`, i'm sure you can find there the option you are looking for.

For the `localOnly` option you can use: `.returnCacheDataDontLoad`

And for the `networkFirst` option maybe the option `.reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData` will suit you well

Comment: Thanks @Marc Garcia, looks like you can use a custom URLSessionConfiguration when creating a service http://bustoutsolutions.github.io/siesta/api/Extensions/URLSessionConfiguration.html#/s:So23URLSessionConfigurationC6SiestaE24siestaNetworkingProviderAC0eF0_pv